# Stop facebook sdk console logs

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Anyone using the facebook sdk(I am using v6.0) for unity must have noticed a plethora of logs on the console that totally dominates the console window obscuring any others logs that you may be wanting to see. I'm sure it was all done with good intentions to help with debugging facebook problems. But now that I'm done with that, I want to get rid of these logs. Is there anyway I can do that? Most of them do not seem to be coming from a 'Debug.Log' otherwise I wud have been able to remove them.